# TSLint: imports of lazy loaded libraries are forbidden: Downgraded Component, Module imported at AppModule and in angular bootstrap

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, tslint, ng-modules

I have a mixed (Angular JS, Angular 8) application where all routing is done at Angular JS.
Let's assume,

```
libs
|--- XYZLibrary/src
     |--- index.ts  // Exports XYZModule and DetailComponent
     |--- lib
          |--- MainComponent  // Component
          |--- DetailComponent  // Component to be downgraded for use at Angular JS
          |--- XYZRoutingModule  // Routing Module, contains routing for MainComponent
          |--- XYZModule  // Module that exports DetailComponent, declares MainComponent, imports XYZRoutingModule
main.ts  // downgrade component DetailComponent
app.module.ts  // AppModule imports XYZModule for DetailComponent downgrading, again lazy loads the same module XYZModule for routing
```

Basically, AppModule imports module **XYZModule** for downgrade component export (for use at AngularJS) and routing through **lazy-loading** syntax *loadChildren, import('...')*.

I am facing a lint error that says:

> ERROR: ../app/app.module.ts:13:1 - imports of lazy-loaded libraries are forbidden
>
> ERROR: ../main.ts:12:1 - imports of lazy-loaded libraries are forbidden

Please help on how can I solve this lint error.